# How can I get a property as an Entity in Action of Asp.Net Mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design

i'd like to know how can I get a property like an entity, for example:

My Model:

```
public class Product {

   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Category Category { get; set; }

}
```

View:

```
Name: <%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) %>
Category: <%= Html.DropDownList("Category", IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Categories"]) %>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Save(Product product)
{
   /// produtct.Category ???
}
```

and how is the category property ? It's fill by the view ? ASP.Net MVC know how to fill this object by ID ?

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably only posting back the category id. You'd need to know on the server side how to get the correct Category instance from your persistence layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the reasons why it's bad to bind directly to entities. Consider

```
public class ProductForm {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string CategoryId { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Save(ProductForm form)
{
   var product = new Product
   {
        Id = form.Id,
        Name = form.Name,
        Category = database.GetCategory(form.CategoryId)
   };
}
```

In case of view models as above, it may be OK to use custom model binders to automatically get entities by Id from database. See [here](http://github.com/codai/Sharp-Architecture/tree/master/src/SharpArch/SharpArch.Web/ModelBinder/) for sample implementation (in [S#arp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net)) that binds IDs to entities from database. But I think for now you better go with simpler implementation like above.

You can also use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) to simplify form->entity mapping.

Comment: I'd also put the list of categories into the view model, rather than in ViewData.

In the Get action for the form, populate the viewmodel including all categories